# Regular expression [a-z_]+ but must contain at least one underscore?

Tags: regex

Given the pattern:

```
[a-z_]+
```

The following are matches:

```
a_cd_f
abcdef
```

Is it possible to allow the first to be a match but ignore the second? I want the pattern requirements as above with the addition that at least one underscore is present.

Comment: Try `[a-z]*_[a-z_]*`. Are there any additional rules? It sounds as if you allow matching a single `_`. Probably, `[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)+` or `^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)+$` is what you really want.

Comment: If letters are mandatory `\b[a-z]+_[a-z_]*`